# How to get data from the database to set the chart's x axis using kendo ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postgresql, kendo-ui

I'm riding a chart using Kendo UI, however necessary that the category x-axis is a month, and what defines the beginning and the end are the startDate and endDate field Postgres database. Example:

startDate: 02/15/2015
enddate: 04/15/2016

Then the x axis of the category will be Feb / 2015 Mar / 2015 ..., Apr / 2016

Below the code, see that the months are fixed, but want it to be in accordance with the start and end fields of the database.

```
<Div id="chart" style="width: 1000px; altura: 2000px"></div>

<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read : {
            url : "rest/project",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "jsonp"
        }
    }
});

console.log(dataSource);

eixox = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
        "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    title : {
        text : "Dashboard Project"
    },
    legend : {
        position : "bottom"
    },
    seriesDefaults : {
        type : "line"
    },


    series : [ {
        name : "Atual",
        data : [ 20, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6 ]

    }, {
        name : "Planejado",
        data : [ 67.96, 68.93, 75, 74, 78 ]

    } ],
    valueAxis : {
        labels : {
            format : "{0}$"
        }
    },

    //VALORES DO EIXO X
    categoryAxis : {

        categories : eixox,

        crosshair : {
            tooltip : {
                format : "Month: {0}",
                visible : true
            },
            visible : true
        }
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my doubt, below is the solution to generate the x axis of the category by month taking into account the date of start and end.

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read : {
            url : "rest/project",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "jsonp"
        }
    }
});

eixox = [];

$("#chart").kendoChart();

$.get("rest/project", { }, function(response){
    date = response[0].startDate.split("-");
    dataInicial = new Date(date[0], date[1] - 1, date[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
    date = response[0].endDate.split("-");
    dataFinal = new Date(date[0], date[1] - 1, date[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    qtdeMeses = Math.ceil((dataFinal - dataInicial) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000));

    qtdeMeses = (qtdeMeses < 12 ? 12 : qtdeMeses);
    mesInicial = dataInicial.getMonth();
    anoInicial = (dataInicial.getFullYear() + "").substr(2, 2);

    for (i = 0; i < qtdeMeses; i++){
        eixox[i] = nomeMeses(mesInicial++) + "/" + anoInicial;

        if(mesInicial == 12){
            mesInicial = 0;
            anoInicial++;
        }
    }

    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title : {
            text : ""
        },
        legend : {
            position : "bottom"
        },
        seriesDefaults : {
            type : "line"
        },


        series : [ {
            name : "Atual",
            data : [ 20, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6 ]

        }, {
            name : "Planejado",
            data : [ 67.96, 68.93, 75, 74, 78 ]
        //LINHA VERDE
        } ],
        valueAxis : {
            labels : {
                format : "{0}$"
            }
        },


        categoryAxis : {

            categories : eixox,

            crosshair : {
                tooltip : {
                    format : "Month: {0}",
                    visible : true
                },
                visible : true
            }
        },

    });
}, "json");

nomeMeses = function(meses){
    switch (meses){
        case 0: var mes = "Jan";break;
        case 1: var mes = "Feb";break;
        case 2: var mes = "Mar";break;
        case 3: var mes = "Apr";break;
        case 4: var mes = "May";break;
        case 5: var mes = "Jun";break;
        case 6: var mes = "Jul";break;
        case 7: var mes = "Aug";break;
        case 8: var mes = "Sep";break;
        case 9: var mes = "Oct";break;
        case 10: var mes = "Nov";break;
        case 11: var mes = "Dec";break;
    }

    return mes;
}
```